# Probability of a egg surviving with a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

The probability that a bird deposits $r$ eggs in its nest is given by the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Assume that the probability of a egg to survive in nature is $p$ and that the survival of each egg is independent.

Knowing that a bird deposited at most $3$ eggs, what is the probability that there is exactly one survival egg?

My attempt to solve this was as follows:

1. P(exactly one survives| at most $3$ deposited) = P(exactly one survives and at most $3$ deposited)/P(at most $3$ deposited)
2. P(at most $3$ deposited) = $\sum_{r=0}^{3}\frac{e^{-\lambda}{\lambda}^r}{r!}$
3. P(exactly one survives and at most $3$ deposited) = $\sum_{r=1}^{3}\frac{e^{-\lambda}{\lambda}^r \cdot {r \choose 1} \cdot p \cdot (1-p)^{r-1}}{r!}$ where the $r=0$ term vanishes because we can't have a egg surviving if there is none in the nest.
4. Finally the result follows dividing 3./2. is that correct, could someone help me?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: It's absolutely correct.                                                                                                     
 The expanded events would be $\frac{\left(P(\text{exactly one survives|one egg})\cdot P(\text{one egg})+P(\text{one egg survives}|\text{two eggs})\cdot P(\text{two eggs})+P(\text{one egg survives|three eggs})\cdot P(\text{three eggs})\right)}{P(\text{at most 3 eggs})}$